# Using Subversion via IntelliJ IDEA With NTLM

Tags: windows, svn, intellij-idea, ntlm

Does anyone know how I can automatically use the current NTLM credentials in IDEA when working with Subversion?

I have IDEA 9.0.4 and get "Not logged In to Subversion '[AD Realm]' (http://[Branch])". (replace [information] with actual technical details) when I try to update/commit/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the following system property -Dsvnkit.http.ntlm=jna - it will make SVNKit use native Windows API through JNA to support JNA. Native implementation may work better for you. Both pure Java and JNA-based implementations of NTLM support in SVNKit however unfortunately does not work well in some environments.

Comment: Where should I put this switch? Also, what is this SvnKit? Is this the way IDEA implements Subversion connectivity?

Comment: You can specify this option in IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions file.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Says "Not logged In to Subversion '[AD Realm]' (http://[Branch])". (replace [information] with actual technical details)

Answer (score 0):

It should work automatically. If you are asked for the password, then the server doesn't accept NTLM auth from SvnKit library for some reason and authentication falls back to different method.

Comment: What is this SvnKit? Is this the way IDEA implements Subversion connectivity?

Comment: Yes, IDEA uses SvnKit library, Java Subversion implementation: http://svnkit.com/ . Alexander Kitaev who replied you is the developer of this library.